# JS ES6 Promises are getting called without reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, promise, es6-promise

I have a problem with promises and the npm "streamToPromise" package.
First of all - I have different functions and when all those functions are resolved I want to call a last function. However in my code - it just get's executed without even going through the iffs inside the "streamToPromise"

```
var func1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ 
// get's executed without reason
  // do something
  if(var1 && var2){
    resolve(true);
  }
});

var func2 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  // get's executed without reason
  // do more
  if(var3 && var4){
    resolve(true);
  }

});

streamToPromise(stream).then(function (operation) {
  // do more 
 // doesn't get executed
  if(varX && varY){
    func1()
    .then(func2)
    .then(func3)
    .then(funcFinal)
    .catch(function (error) {
      // console log error
    }
  }
}
```

I've been trying to understand Promises for a few weeks now but there are always some errors I don't understand. Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've created `func1` `func2` etc, but they are not functions, they are promises that have been "created" immediately, therefore the code inside `new Promise` executor has been called immediately

you want func1 etc to be functions, then make them functions

```
var func1 = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // get's executed without reason
        // do something
        if (var1 && var2) {
            resolve(true);
        }
    });
}

var func2 = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // get's executed without reason
        // do more
        if (var3 && var4) {
            resolve(true);
        }
    });
}

streamToPromise(stream).then(function(operation) {
    if (varX && varY) {
        func1()
            .then(func2)
            .then(func3)
            .then(funcFinal)
            .catch(function(error) {
                    // console log error
                }
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`func1` and `func2` aren't actually functions; they're promises that you create immediately.

You probably want those to be functions that return promises.

You also don't want to call them and pass their results to `then()`; you want to pass the functions themselves.

Comment: I tried that - but the problem is that it dosn't even get to this point. The functions are getting called before. Is this because I'm creating the Promise functions as vars and they get initialized?

Comment: @TimoReichert: You tried _what_? You have two different mistakes, each of which will cause this problem.

Comment: I changed the functions to the name of the functions.

So I can't create those promises in advance? Is there an alternative? Should I just create functions and promises above them? Sorry if this might sound stupid but I have a really hard time understanding how promises really work.

Comment: @TimoReichert: A promise is just an object.  The callback you pass to `new Promise()` runs immediately.  If you want a function that returns a promise (as opposed to creating promises immediately), you need to make a function.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is the way method being called

either use  this way

```
.then(function () {
return func2();
}).then( ...)
```

for that in func2() and func3() you need to return Promise object

or use ( without paranthesis )

```
.then(func2).then(func3)
```

Comment: I tried that - but the problem is that it dosn't even get to this point. The functions are getting called before. Is this because I'm creating the Promise functions as vars and they get initialized?